# How do I find Taekwondo Tournaments near me?

Tags: tae-kwon-do

I am looking for open Taekwondo tournaments that *do not* require for you to be in any specific organization to enter.

How would I go about finding those?

Comment: I dont think this needs to be specific to Alabama, or Tae-kwon-do - I am sure the same problem exists regardless of location and art

Answer (score 2):

ITF and in the UK here,
There are not many truly open tournaments around so heres a couple of ideas:

**Widen your search** - look at freestyle karate/kickboxing (more useful for sparring - some do open Kata as well which will let you do patterns)

**Ask the groups** - usually the closed competitions it is for insurance or conformity reasons, if you talk to the heads of the organisations posting tournaments locally you may be allowed to compete - they may ask you to purchase insurance or similar. Just be aware that while most judging is fair - some referees may take a negative view of you if you are not wearing the correct dobok and you may have to win more convincingly.

**Join a larger group as well** - competitions are one of the benefits of the larger groups, see if you can train occasionally and keep your insurance and membership up to date to allow you to compete. They are unlikely to stop you training at a small independent local school as well (they may have more of an issue if you are instructing*)

Answer (score 2):

Look for schools and instructors in your area and talk to them.

Schools usually organize smaller competitions between them, to help prepare their students for larger events. Since these are organized between schools and not by an official organization, they can be open to other people.

Answer (score -2):

There's a list of all open taekwondo tournaments at https://www.taekwondotournaments.org/wtf.html

I'm assuming you already checked there?

They have one for ITF too, but it's smaller.